# java spring webflux websocket binary message

Tags: javascript, websocket, spring-webflux

i can send from client side to WebFlux and see the string bug how can i send back to client side and that the client side be able to parse it is something i can't figure out .
this is what have as server using java spring WebFlux ;

```
 public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

        Flux<WebSocketMessage> output2 = session.receive()
                .doOnNext(message -> {
                        logger.info("Recived from client:"+message.getPayloadAsText());
                })
                .map(value -> session.textMessage("Echo " + value.getPayloadAsText()));

        return session.send(output2);

    }
```

And this is the client :

```
var WebSocket = WebSocket || window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket; 


_stringConvertToArray = function(strData) {
if (!strData)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var arrData = new Uint16Array(strData.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < strData.length; i++) {
        arrData[i] = strData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return arrData;
};
_stringConvertToUint8Array = function (strData) {
        
    // View the byte buffer as an array of 8-bit unsigned integers
    var arrData = new Uint8Array(strData.length);
    for (var i=0;i<strData.length;++i) {
        arrData[i] = strData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // Log the binary array
    console.log("SEND ARRAY BUFFER: " + arrData.buffer);
    return arrData;
};

var connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8001/test");
connection.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
connection.onopen = function(evt) {
    console.log("Send Binary WS was opened.");
};

connection.onmessage = (function(evt) {
        console.log(evt.currentTarget.binaryType);
        var binaryUint8 = new Uint8Array(evt.data);
        var binaryStr = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < binaryUint8.length; i++) {
            binaryStr += String.fromCharCode(binaryUint8[i]);
        }
        console.log("recived from server:"+binaryStr);
        

        connection.onerror = function(evt) {
            //this.m_loginObj.serverofflineLabel = 180;
            conosle.log("connection Error was fired");
            
        };

        connection.onclose = function(evt) {
            conosle.log("connection websocket instance closed.");
            connection = null;
        };
               
 })



var sendMassage = function(reqJson)
{

    if (this.connection.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN)
    {
        var buf = reqJson;//Encode(reqJson);
        var binary = this._stringConvertToUint8Array(buf);
        this.connection.send(binary.buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        var warningStr = "send binary websocket instance wasn't ready...try again in few seconds";
        console.log(warningStr);
        this.init();
        
            
    }
};
```

in the function :  connection.onmessage i keep getting empty data .